# Design state tree for search, filter, paging and refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm developing a React Native app using redux. My app have a home page will show a list of movies and a search bar in top of screen. A setting page for user to select filter fields.

Follow real-world app in redux homepage. ([real-world](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world))

I design state tree of my app following :

```
{
 entities: {
   movies: {
    id1: {
       id1.
       title,
       ....
    }  
  },
  pagination:{
    movies: {
    }
  },
  meta: {
     search: '',
     filter1: '',
     filter2: true,
     filter3: ''
  }
}
```

In the first time go to home page, I use meta props to create a key like this

```
key="keyword=&filter1=&filter2=true&filter3=";
```

So the state tree will become :

```
pagination:{
   'keyword=&filter1=&filter2=true&filter3='{
     fetching: false,
     ids: [id1, id2, ...]
     offset: 0,
    }
  }
```

If I use search box and search with keyword "hello", the key will be come :

```
key="keyword=hello&filter1=&filter2=true&filter3=";
```

and the state tree will become :

```
pagination:{
   'keyword=&filter1=&filter2=true&filter3='{
     fetching: false,
     ids: [id1, id2, ...]
     offset: 0,
    },
    'keyword=hello&filter1=&filter2=true&filter3='{
     fetching: false,
     ids: [id1, id2, ...]
     offset: 0,
    }
  }
```

So my question: Is it a good idea to use this approach to design state tree ? Could you give a better suggestion for design state for my app ?

And when I implement pull to refresh feature, Do I need to remove all of ids fields of a key or just need to update offset = 0 and reload ids arrays ???

I hope you guys can understand me because my english is not good.

Thank you !

Comment: Hi CodeMonster, I am not able to understand your question. Are you using reducer? if you have implemented some code then do share.

Comment: Yes, I use reducer. But now, i just want to talk about state tree in redux. Have you read the real-world app ?